# Pandas Dataframe - copy multiple column values and paste them to other two columns based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### A   B   C   D   E

aa  bb
aa  bb
aa  bb

```
    cc  dd  ee
    cc  dd  ee
    cc  dd  ee
```

aa  bb
aa  bb
aa  bb

The above is a representation of a merged pandas dataframe.   Wherever column C is not null, I want to copy values from column D and column E and paste them in column A and column B respectively.  I can use this by giving two separate df.apply(lambda ..) command.  I want to achieve this in one line using a user defined function like this.  However I am not able to achieve the same as I am getting errors.  Please suggest a solution.

```
def func(row):
    if row['C']=='cc':
        return([['D'],['E']])

df[['A'],['B']] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna), which is made for this:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].fillna(value = {'A':df['D'],'B':df['E']})
```

It the column `C` really matters, than [`mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) is also a very valid solution:

```
df['A'].mask(df['C'].notna(), df['D'], inplace=True)
df['B'].mask(df['C'].notna(), df['E'], inplace=True)
```